# Add new column based on groupby map in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df as shown below

```
product     bought_date      number_of_sales 
A           2016             15
A           2017             10
A           2018             15
B           2016             20
B           2017             30
B           2018             20
C           2016             20
C           2017             30
C           2018             20
```

From the above I would like to add one column called cost_per_unit as shown below.

cost of product A is 100, B is 500 and C is 200

```
d1 = {'A':100, 'B':500, 'C':'200'}
```

Expected Output:

```
product     bought_date      number_of_sales   cost_per_unit
A           2016             15                100
A           2017             10                100
A           2018             15                100
B           2016             20                500
B           2017             30                500
B           2018             20                500
C           2016             20                200
C           2017             30                200
C           2018             20                200
```

Comment: Use `df['cost_per_unit'] = df['product'].map(d1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for any *lambda* function. Run just:

```
df['cost_per_unit'] = df['product'].map(d1)
```

Additional remark: *product* is a name of a *Pandas* function. You should avoid
column names "covering" existing functions or attributes.
It is a good habit, that they should differ, at least in char case.

Comment: which column name is an existing function? product?

Comment: The name of function is *product*. Run e.g. *df.product()*. This is why you can not write e.g. *df.product.map(d1)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['cost_per_unit'] = df.apply(lambda x: d1[x['product']], axis=1)
print(df)

  product  bought_date  number_of_sales cost_per_unit
0       A         2016               15           100
1       A         2017               10           100
2       A         2018               15           100
3       B         2016               20           500
4       B         2017               30           500
5       B         2018               20           500
6       C         2016               20           200
7       C         2017               30           200
8       C         2018               20           200
```